# cout will not display object in array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have an array with currently two objects. When ran, the display is "0".

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <process.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int lBlock = rand() % 99 + 10;
int rBlock = lBlock + 1;
string randBlock[15] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
string blocks[2] = {("0x", lBlock, randBlock[rand() % 14], "0"), ("0x", lBlock, randBlock[rand() % 14], "0")};
cout << blocks[1];
```

Any help will be greatly apreciated!

Comment: because `blocks[1]` contains `"0"`

Comment: This isn't really relevant but `using namespace std` is generally considered a bad practice because it pollutes the namespace.

Comment: This isn't even valid C++. Statements can't exist outside of a function. Where's `main()`?

Comment: What do you expect `("0x", lBlock, randBlock[rand() % 14], "0")` to do?

Comment: please tell us what do you think your code does and what did you expect to print?

Comment: You cannot call functions outside of any function scope. Did you miss to embed that code into `int main { }`?

Comment: @Ron why not?...

Comment: Please read up on the [`std::string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), I don't see any constructors that convert an integer value.

Comment: @bolov Lacks a seed.

Comment: @Ron yes it does lack a seed. Still random though.

Comment: Looks like you may want to create a `struct` or `class` to represent a block (for the `blocks` array).

Comment: @HeikoKoelle I would not recommend doing that but `using namespace` in cpp file is personal preference. Doing so in header would be harmful.

Comment: @Slava Both are harmful in different ways. In a header it's more harmful, but it's still harmful in a cpp file.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead consider marking an answer as accepted which will tell others that is has now been solved. Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to include the main() function in my code example but it is in my code and im sorry for the confusion. I would also like to ask what Heiko Koell means by "pollutes the namespace". Im kinda new to c++. This has also been solved by @cdhowie and I thank you all for your input.

Comment: @Joe if an answer has solved you problem consider to accept the answer (the green check mark) next to answer, see [tour]

Comment: @JoeStandring It takes all of the names in the `std` namespace and throws them into your global namespace.  This can cause ambiguity errors at best, or silent usage of the wrong type at worst.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
("0x", lBlock, randBlock[rand() % 14], "0")
```

This expression invokes the [comma (`,`) operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) three times.

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its result is discarded ... and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression `E2` begins.
>
> The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand, `E2`.

To put it another way, `(a, b) == b`, assuming that:

- `b == b`
- The expression `a` does not cause any side effects that could cause `b != b`.

Therefore, the above expression is equivalent to `"0"` (except for the side effect of calling `rand()`).  `std::cout` is correctly displaying this value.

It looks like you probably meant this instead:

```
std::string("0x") + std::to_string(lBlock) + randBlock[rand() % 14] + "0"
```